# Problem of converting timestamp in mysql code by using from_unixtime

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I am trying to convert the timestamp to date format by using `from_unixtime(timestamp_utc)` but i couldn't be successfull, can you help me please!!

```
public function kamp_yon_ozt_rek_tracker() {
    $id=Auth::user()->id;
    $all=DB::table('kampanya_yonetimi')
           ->join('reklam_yukleme','kampanya_yonetimi.reklam_yukleme_id','=','reklam_yukleme.id')
           ->join('kampanya_ozeti','kampanya_yonetimi.kampanya_ozeti_id','=','kampanya_ozeti.id')
           ->join('tracker_results','kampanya_yonetimi.file','=','tracker_results.title')
        ->where('kampanya_yonetimi.user_id','=',$id)
        ->whereBetween('from_unixtime(tracker_results.timestamp_utc)', ['2019-01-01 11:59:57', now()->addDays
        (0)])
            ->orderBy('from_unixtime(tracker_results.timestamp_utc)')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy(function ($val) {
                return Carbon::parse($val->timestamp_utc);
                //->format('Y/m/d');
            });

    return $all;
}
```

> Unknown column 'from_unixtime(tracker_results.timestamp_utc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default eloquent/DB query builder will apply back quote(`) enclosed to whatever inside it. For this problem, You can use`DB::raw` here to consider it as is,

```
->orderBy(DB::raw('FROM_UNIXTIME(tracker_results.timestamp_utc)'))
```

Change your line with mine. It should work.

> **Note:** I suggest you should use capital cases for core MySQL functions for better readability and standards i.e. `FROM_UNIXTIME`.

Comment: thanks sir, also i have used  ;
                
    ->whereBetween(DB::raw('FROM_UNIXTIME(tracker_results.timestamp_utc)')   ,  then i have fixed the problem